# Hyperlinks in theorem names

Tags: hyperref, links, amsthm, thmtools

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,thmtools,hyperref}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=\mw@mystyleposthead,
name={\ignorespaces},
numbered=no,
headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{thm}

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{thm1}{}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}[name=Exension of \hyperlink{thm1}{the one above}]
The extension. The extension. The extension. The extension.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I am terribly simplifying my actual context. THe aim is to put the `\hyperlink` in the theorem name. However, in the code I get the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\th@mystyle ...@indent \noindent \thm@headsep \mw 
                                                  @mystyleposthead\relax \th...
l.23 S
      ome theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem.
```

In my context I get:

```
Use of \\thmt@setnewoptarg doesn't match its definit
ion.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.276 ...ttr}[name=Extension of \hyperlink{gu}{1}]
```

Adding `fontspec` to the code above turns the error into:

```
Runaway argument?
\x@protect \[\protect \[  \@nil  \@ifpackageloaded {amstex}{\def \@tempa \ETC.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty:435: Paragraph e
nded before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.435 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
```

So the question is: why the error changes? I know it won't be easy (or maybe even possible) to explain what is changing in "my context", but I'm afraid I can't post that context since it uses my own package. So you can avoid answering about my context. The other question is, as the title suggests, the main question: how do I get the hyperlink in the theorem name?

**Edit:**
As David Carlisle noted, I am missing a `\makeatletter`, but not only. Adding:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\mw@mystyleposthead
\mw@mystyleposthead=0.5em
```

just before the `\declaretheoremstyle` and calling `noindentafter` too, and finally changing `thm` to `@thmattr` turns the error into:

```
Runaway argument?
\x@protect \[\protect \[  \@nil  \@ifpackageloaded {amstex}{\def \@tempa \ETC.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty:435: Paragraph e
nded before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.435 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
```

and removing `fontspec` turns the error into:

```
./thmname@hyperlink@MWE.tex:27: Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.27 ...ension of \hyperlink{thm1}{the one above}]
```

So the error with `fontspec` is the same as before, while the error without has changed, and is still not the one in my context, which, cut down as far as I can get without altering the error (or almost), is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse,thmtools,mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
%Declares theorem style mystyle. Requires amsthm.
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=0.5em,
name={\ignorespaces},
numbered=no,
headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
%Declares theorem @thmattr with style mystyle. Now this is a class of theorems which is instanced by the xtheor environment, which is a big mess of coding and which I will comment inside the code, also to make it more readable to myself.
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\newcommand{\refstyle}[1]{{\bfseries\color{blue}#1}}
\newcommand{\setrefstyle}{\renewcommand\refstyle[1]}
\newcommand{\resetrefstyle}{\renewcommand{\refstyle}[1]{{\bfseries\color{purple!60!black}##1}}}
\newcommand{\setmwref}[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname mw@thmref@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\setmwrefb}[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname mw@thmrefb@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\setmwrefc}[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname mw@thmrefc@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\getmwref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\refstyle{\csname mw@thmref@#1\endcsname}}}
\newcommand{\getmwrefb}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\refstyle{\csname mw@thmrefb@#1\endcsname}}}
\newcommand{\getmwrefc}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\refstyle{\csname mw@thmrefc@#1\endcsname}}}
\newcommand{\refprep}{di}
\newcommand{\setprep}{\renewcommand\refprep}
\newcommand{\@rel}[1]{\ (#1)}
\newcommand{\setrel}{\renewcommand\@rel[1]}
\newcommand{\resetrel}{\renewcommand{\@rel}[1]{\ (##1)}}
\newcommand{\@lrel}[1]{:\ #1}
\newcommand{\setlrel}{\renewcommand\@lrel[1]}
\newcommand{\resetlrel}{\renewcommand{\@lrel}[1]{:\ ##1}}
\newcommand{\contrel}[1]{\ (continua da #1)}
\newcommand{\setcontrel}{\renewcommand\contrel[1]}
\newcommand{\resetcontrel}{\renewcommand{\contrel}[1]{\ (continua da ##1)}}
\newcommand{\setpage}[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1@savedpage\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\getpage}[1]{\csname #1@savedpage\endcsname}
\newcommand{\setcnt}[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1@savedcnt\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\getcnt}[1]{\csname #1@savedcnt\endcsname}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%Here we are: xtheor.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xtheor}{moO{x}oood()}%Many arguments, one mandatory and 5 optional, with default only for the second optional, set to x.
{\IfValueTF{#5}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\hypertarget{#5}{}\setpage{#5}{\thepage}\setcnt{#5}{\@ifundefined{c@#2}{1}{\arabic{#2}}}}{}}{}%\@ifundefined{\csname mw@thmref@#5\endcsname}{}{\PackageWarning{mworkx}{Label #5 already used}}{}
\IfNoValueTF{#2}%Is there a 2?
      {\def\theorem@attr{#1\IfValueTF{#7}{\contrel{\hyperlink{#5}{#7}}}{}}\IfValueTF{#5}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\setmwref{#5}{#1}}{}}{}}%No? Then \theorem@attr, which will probably become the theorem's name, is #1. And so is the reference.
      {\@ifundefined{c@#2}%There IS a 2? OK then it's a mess. Because it means we have a counter sequence to create. So is there a counter named like 2?
            {\newcounter{#2} \setcounter{#2}{1}}%No? Make it. And set it to 1. Obvously it's the first theorem of that kind.
            {\addtocounter{#2}{+1}}%Yes? Then just increase it by +1.
      \ifnum\c@chapter>0
          \ifnum\c@section>0
              \ifnum\c@subsection>0
                  \xdef\acounters{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\arabic{#2}}{\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}}
              \else
                  \xdef\acounters{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\arabic{#2}}{\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}}
              \fi
          \else
              \xdef\acounters{\arabic{chapter}.\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\arabic{#2}}{\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}}
          \fi
      \else
          \xdef\acounters{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{\arabic{#2}}{\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}}
      \fi
      \def\counters{%Now we create the counter sequence.
      \str_case:nnF{#3}%We test argument 3.
      {
          {c}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{#2}}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}
          }%c stands for chapter numbering, so if #3 is c the counters are chapter, separating dot, #2, all in arabic representation.
          {s}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{#2}}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}
          }%s stands for section, so if #3 is s we have chapter, dot, section, dot #2.
          {x}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{#2}}
              {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}
          }%x is subsection, so to those above we add the subsection counter.
          {n}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}
              {\arabic{#2}}
              {\csname #5@savedcnt \endcsname}
          }%n stands for none, so just #2.
          {a}{\acounters}%Finally, a stands for automatic, which means if any of chapter, section or subsection is positive (i.e. not 0 and not negative), they are put in this order with separating dots, then we have, of course, #2. This is actually dealt with by the nested \ifs in the definition of \acounters, for if those \ifs were placed in here, it wouldn't work. I tried that. Trust me :).
           {@@}{}%If it is @@, no counters at all, not even #2. That is to be able to use #5 (the label) when we have a special theorem which needs no number.
           }
           {\errmessage{Illegal argument in counter definition}%What? None of those before? Error: illegal argument.
            \errhelp{The third argument must be either c, s or x, for chapter, section and subsection respectively, or n for none of those, or a to let me choose the counters automatically, or @@ for no counters at all.}}
        }%So now we have the counter sequence.
        \IfValueTF{#5}{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{
            \setmwref{#5}{#1\ \counters}
            \setmwrefb{#5}{#1\ \refprep\ #4}
            \setmwrefc{#5}{#1:\ #4}}
        {}}{}
                 \edef\theorem@attr{
                     #1
                     \str_if_eq:nnTF{#3}{@@}
                         {}
                         {\,\,}
                     \counters
                     \IfValueTF{#7}
                         {\contrel{#7}}
                         {}
                     }}%At this point, we define \theorem@attr, which is the theorem's name, to be #1, which is the theorem kind or full theorem name when it's counterless, and #1 plus two \,s plus #4 when #3 is neither nothing nor @@. The spacing between the counters and #4 and company if present is handled by \@rel.
                 \def\name@thmlist{
                         #1\IfValueTF{#2}
                                            {\ \counters}
                                            {}
                         \IfValueTF{#4}
                                             {\IfValueTF{#6}
                                                 {\@lrel{#6}}
                                                 {\@lrel{#4}}
                                             }
                                             {}
                         }%And we define \name@thmlist, which, as the name says, is the theorem's name in the \listoftheorems. This is #1, plus \ \counters, when #2 is present, plus #4 if present without #6, and plus #6 if #4 and #6 are present, in any case separated from \counters as specified by \@lrel if \counters doesn't end \name@thmlist. Requesting both presences is not restrictive, as no #4 implies no #6.
\IfNoValueTF{#7}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#4}%Now we wonder: is #4 present?
        {\begin{@thmattr}[{name=[\name@thmlist]\theorem@attr}]}%No? Then we finally start a @thmattr with name \theorem@attr and name in the list \name@thmlist.
        {\str_if_eq:nnTF{#4}{\ }
            {\begin{@thmattr}[{name=[\name@thmlist]\theorem@attr}]}
            {\begin{@thmattr}[{name=[\name@thmlist]\theorem@attr\@rel{#4}}]}
            }}%Since the label in #5 is dealt with before, we don't need to do anything about it now, so we only ask if #4 is \ , in which case we ignore it, otherwise we put it next to \theorem@attr as specified by \@rel.
     {\begin{@thmattr}[name=\theorem@attr]}
}
%Note that in all cases, though \theorem@attr is followed by a space before (, it is ignored. That's why \theorem@attr contains that \,\, we saw before. Same thing as before concerning the #4=space case.
{\end{@thmattr}}%And in the \end part, just end the @thmattr.
%From this analysis, we see that:
%1: #1 is the theorem kind (Theorem, Remark, Proposition, Lemma, etc) or the full theorem name in case of a theorem with a special name like the Hairy Ball Theorem, which has no counter. That's why it's the only mandatory argument;
%2: #2 is the name of the counter associated with that theorem kind;
%3: #3 is a parameter to decide the counter style: c corresponding to [chapter] in plain theorem declarations (\newtheorem{foo}[chapter]), s corresponding to [section], x corresponding to [subsection], and n for a lone counter, probably for exercises;
%4: #4 is the theorem's name in the page where it is started; if #6 is given, this corresponds to foo in {name=[bar]foo}, otherwise it is the foo in name=foo;
%5: #5 is the label, so label=foo corresponds to foo in #5;
%6: #6, finally, is the name in the \listoftheorems, thus corresponds to the bar in {name=[bar]foo}.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\xtheorsetlist}{\renewcommand\thmt@listnumwidth{-1.5em}}%This is sort of forced by the use of xtheor, so to speed it up I've made it into a command.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\xtheorsetlist

\begin{document}
\begin{xtheor}{Teorema}[teor][s][Bogus][thm:teor:Bogus]

\end{xtheor}
\getmwref{thm:teor:Bogus}
\hypertarget{gu}{}
\begin{@thmattr}[name=1]

\end{@thmattr}

\begin{@thmattr}[name=Extension of \hyperlink{gu}{1}]

\end{@thmattr}


\end{document}
%10 adding d() and doing nested delimiter thing and 2 comment. 13 fixing last thing about labels and 1 comment. 2 fixing problems IN THIS DOCUMENT (\setrefstyle{}, no inputenc) and 2 comment.
```

It seems `\getmwref{thm:teor:Bogus}` is disturbing the last `@thmattr`, changing the error.

Comment: `\mw @mys` ==> you forgot a `\makeatletter` if `@` is not a letter `postheadspace=\mw@mystyleposthead,` is `postheadspace=\mw   @mystyleposthead,`

Comment: Yep, that's right. In fact, I completely forgot about `\mw@mystyleposthead` when copy-pasting the style code :). Does that make the error become the one of "my context"?

Comment: And what happens when I add `fontspec` that changes the error?

Comment: you didn't need to remember, the error message (for once) pointed straight at the problem:-) then of course you get undefined command `\mw@mystyleposthead ` as you haven't defined it but it's unconnected with the hyperlink

Comment: I added fontspec but got the same error, but you confuse tex that much what it does next is fairly arbitrary

Comment: In what sense do I "confuse" TeX?

Comment: Giving it the tokens `@ m y s t y l e p o s t h e a d` which will just be tipped into the internals of the theorem environment and break that and then probably try to typeset themselves before `\begin{document}` has set up the document fonts...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please see the edit. Anyway the answer to the main question was to `\protect` that `\hyperlink`, as you said in your post. On a theoretical level, I guess `\hyperlink` is a fragile command which breaks in the moving argument that the theorem name is. Is that right?

Comment: So we are left with just one last question: what is `fontspec` doing that changes the error?

Comment: as I say, when I added fontspec the error didn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message showed, the problem was

```
\mw 
   @mystyleposthead
```

which shows that `\mw@mystyleposthead` was not parsed as a token, which shows that `@` was not a letter. Fixing that (I just replaced it by 10pt here) it all works once you `\protect`  `\hyperlink`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,thmtools,hyperref}


\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\topsep, 
spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=10pt,
name={\ignorespaces},
numbered=no,
headpunct=.]
{mystyle}


\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{thm}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{thm1}{}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem. Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}[name=Exension of \protect\hyperlink{thm1}{the one above}]
The extension. The extension. The extension. The extension.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```